# UTP Patch box for on a desk

Tags: networking, cabling

I want some UTP cabling from a cabinet terminated on a desk, much like a patch panel in a 19" rack. But since it is on a desk, and no 19" rack is available there, I was wondering if there were products that have the same function, but are nicer to put on a desk. Something that looks more like a home switch.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your desk - but, I would suggest:

Terminating to a socket similar to this:

[image]

and finding a nice backbox or similar that matches the design of your room/desk and make it look all nice, or buy an all in one box + front - for example:

[image]

There are many similar products - Just search for RJ45 mounts/boxes/desk etc.

Or if this was my room... just terminate to a RJ45 plug and leave it on your desk!